Any way to make NeoVim choose tag which refers to current file or to closest file?
I use NeoVim with universal ctags tags file. It works more or less fine, but:

if I have a method with a common name, e.g. .isOpen()
or when I have some duplicated code in a project (in which case it's more annoying, because it's easier to overlook that you are in a wrong place)

When I press Ctrl+] NeoVim frequently throws me to a wrong location.
I'm used to it so I just trained myself to watch if the file is one I'd expect and if it's not just go back, wipe the previous buffer, press g,Ctrl+] and select a correct location.
But may be there already exists a way for NeoVim to sort the tags by the file they refer to in a certain priority, e.g.:

current file
files which have the most common path with the current file

I appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Not exactly what you ask but you could be interested by using: [Ctrl I`. It searches from the top of the file (skipping comments) the word under the cursor (it is very often a good approximation of go to definition).
More information with :help [_CTRL-I

thank you, I didn't know this

You are welcome! Thanks for the feedback :-)

As of now I consider the problem solved. Not a bulletproof solution which may
not work in every case, though, but I thought that it would be worth to write
an answer.
So here are the steps I took.
Step 1: Read man ctags. The tool is rather rich and it's worth the effort to get
familiar with concepts, options etc.
Step 2: Generate separate tags files for different languages. With options tailored
for the language (if needed). I.e. just run it with default 'extras', 'kinds'
etc. and see what's in the generated tags file. If it has something you can
consider garbage, try to tweak the extras and kinds options.
E.g. in my case the PHP tags file worked normally with everything default. But
for JavaScript I had to remove the 'pseudo' extra and many kinds (this is a
term from man ctags).
And provide just directories, not actual file names to ctags
Previously I used to do:
ctags ./dir-1/**/*js ./dir-N/**/*.js
//======== the options/js.txt file:
-f ./path-to/tags/js
--tag-relative=never
--recurse
--exclude=*.min.js
--exclude=*externals*
--exclude=*test*

Now I do:
ctags --options=./path-to/options/js.txt ./dir-1/ ./dir-N/
//======== the options/js.txt file:
-f ./path-to/tags/js
--tag-relative=never
--recurse
--exclude=*.min.js
--exclude=*externals*
--exclude=*test*
--kinds-JavaScript=-MGSCp
--extras=-{pseudo}
--languages=JavaScript

As one can see, now I provide only directories (not sure if it improved
anything) and I generate tags only for JavaScript with the --kinds-JavaScript
and --extras options provided.
In NeoVim set the tags option dynamically with the FileType autocommand.
autocmd FileType php setlocal tags=path-to/tags/php
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal tags=path-to/tags/js

Step 3: also additionally I parse the generated tags file with a Perl script, which
goes over every line and if it starts with 'anonymous'-something I either check
if an identifier can be found in the ex command field (another term from man ctags).
E.g. if the ex command field contains something like:
/^        myMethod: function

then I take that identifier and put it in place of the anonymous-something
(i.e.) in the NAME field. Otherwise just discard this line, b/c I'm not sure
how those anonymous things can be useful.
Then I sort the updated lines and save the tags file.
Currently it works sufficiently although the Perl script step looks rather ugly. I worked with it for a couple of hours today,
didn't spot any problems.

You might consider prepending or appending to the tags option instead of overwriting it completely.
